# How to change all stock prices to USD?

Tags: curated-data, units, finance

I want to create DateListPlot that compares prices of cellphone manufacturers' stocks over the last 13 years. Stocks include Nokia, Blackberry, Samsung, LG, Motorola, and Sony-Ericsson.
The problem is Samsung's and LG's stocks are in Korean Wons.
I wrote a function that applies a UnitConvert to the price, it works with the a singular example, and small batches of data, but it refuses to run through the entire dataset. What could be the issue? Some errors in data? Should I clean it?
Code:

```
sams1 = FinancialData["KS:005930", {2006, 1, 1}];

Convert[n_] := UnitConvert[Quantity[n, "KoreanWon"], "USDollars"]
ApplyFormat[list_] := {list[[1]], Convert[list[[2]]]}

ApplyFormat[sams1[[1]]]

ApplyFormat /@ sams1 (* This one refuses to work *)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refuses to run"?  Does it give an error?

Comment: try `Cases[sams1, {{a__}, b_} -> {{a}, Convert@b}]`

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `UnitConvert[Quantity[n, "KoreanWon"], "USDollars"]` for every value of `n`.  `UnitConvert` might be making an internet query for every time you do a currency conversion, so if `sams1` is a long list then you are making many such calls.  In this case it's wasteful since you could just compute the conversion rate once and use it over again.

Use either

```
sams1[[All, 2]] *= UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "KoreanWon"], "USDollars"]
```

or take advantage of the fact that `UnitConvert` and `Quantity` automatically thread over lists and use

```
sams1[[All,2]] = UnitConvert[Quantity[sams1[[All,2]], "KoreanWon"], "USDollars"]
```

either way, you only make one request for the conversion factor.